# How do I create task lists in Jorte?

Tags: jorte

How do I create task lists other than `My Task List`?

Also, how many task lists can be created in Jorte?

Answer (score 1):

Open up Jorte and go to the "Tasks & Memos" section. Click on the "Task List" button, and there should be a "Create" button that lets you create a new list.

To view other lists, go back to the "Task List" button and check/uncheck the lists you wish to show/hide.

I don't know if there is a limit to the number of lists you are able to have in Jorte; I would imagine the number is a technical one that is much higher than an average user would ever need.

Answer (score 1):

the max amount of task lists appears to be 3, at least for me anyways!